# Can't able to set expiry date in cookie using javascript?

Tags: javascript, session, cookies, browser

I am using following function

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays){
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

setCookie("userName","vimalraj.s",1);
```

It create cookies in a "session " not with a 24 hours expiry time .

how to fix this ?

UPDATE :

The above code works fine in my colleague's computer   Firefox(27.0.1)
and it doesn't for me same Firefox version

I even tried "max-age" instead of "expires"

```
function set_cookie ( cookie_name, cookie_value,
    lifespan_in_days, valid_domain )
{
    // http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/cookies.shtml
    var domain_string = valid_domain ?
                       ("; domain=" + valid_domain) : '' ;
    document.cookie = cookie_name +
                       "=" + encodeURIComponent( cookie_value ) +
                       "; max-age=" + 60 * 60 *
                       24 * lifespan_in_days +
                       "; path=/" + domain_string ;
}
```

Nothing worked ...

Comment: I think creating a new cookie with same details and new expires will override the existing cookie with new one.

Comment: Sorry if you know this. Make sure you are testing your cookie stuff from a valid domain (localhost is not a valid domain and will cause a bag of trouble)

Comment: Thanks for your responses, it may be a problem due to my Firefox version

Comment: My code works fine in Google Chrome, surely i have a problem in Firefox

Answer (score 1):

Taken from quirksmode.org.

```
    function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

Here is for one day

createCookie('ppkcookie','testcookie',1)

Comment: quirksmode example or not! people who write javascript omitting curly brace should be shot!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a new cookie with same cookie name.

now you can set the new expire.
This will over ride the existing cookie since both are of same name.

Now the new cookie will have the new expires

old cookie

```
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60*1000));
var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
```

new cookie

```
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60*1000));
var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
```

I hope this will help